# Exception while running SOAP servcie

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wcf, soap

I m developing a server application. It is a windows service running on server machine. To interact with server service, I exposed WCF service. Other clients can interact with server by consuming WCF service. But it limits the user to develop only windows based system, we decided to expose SOAP service also. I am in middle of development of the same. SOAP service is running on IIS and interact to WCF service but user is unaware about WCF service instead they know about SOAP only. WCF service uses userdefined/complex data types. When I consume WCF service (to interact with server) in SOAP project, user defined types (which WCF is using) are accessible. I exposed a method and tried to access the results but "NetDispatcheFaultException" was thrown. There are several userdefined types but the type which is creating problem is as follows:

```
public class ServerConfig
{

    private List<License> _licenseConfiguration;

    public ServerConfig()
    {
        _licenseConfiguration = new List<License>();
    }

    [XmlArray("licenseconfiguration", IsNullable = true)]
    [XmlArrayItem("license", typeof(License))]
    public List<License> LicenseConfiguration { get { return _licenseConfiguration; } set { _licenseConfiguration = value; } }


    public string[] AcquiredLicenses
    {
        get
        {
            int index = 0;
            string[] licenses = new string[LicenseConfiguration.Count];
            foreach (License lic in LicenseConfiguration)
            {
                licenses[index] = Utils.GetUserFriendlyNameFor(lic.LicenseName);
                index++;
            }
            return licenses;
        }
    }       
}

public class License
{
    [XmlAttribute("licensename")]
    public LicenseTypes LicenseName { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("licensecount")]
    public int LicenseCount { get; set; }

    public License()
    {
        this.LicenseName = LicenseTypes.None;
        this.LicenseCount = 0;
    }
    public License(LicenseTypes licenseName)
    {
        this.LicenseName = licenseName;
        this.LicenseCount = 0;
    }
    public FbFLicense(LicenseTypes licenseName, int count)
    {
        this.LicenseName = licenseName;
        this.LicenseCount = count;
    }

}
```

When SOAP service runs, I invoke following method, which in turns invoke WCF method:

```
[WebMethod]
    public ServerConfig GetServerConfiguration()
    {
        return base.ServerConfiguration();//.ServerConfiguration();
    }
```

On invoking this method everything executes smoothly on WCF side but it throws following exception on SOAP side:

[image]

Why it is happening ? Suggest some way to fix this. This exception disappears if Either I remove

```
public string[] AcquiredLicenses
```

property from ServerConfig class or just change the return type from "string[]" to "List(string)".
Any IDea?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set reader quotas. Probably array is too large to deserialize. 
[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731325.aspx)